# handling non-standard escape sequences on a hardware terminal

Tags: terminal, hardware, escape-characters

This is somewhat exotic. I'm writing a program that uses an old vt100 compatible terminal ([minitel 1b](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minitel)) as the user interface.

My program access the minitel directly through `/dev/ttyUSB0`. Following [online resources](http://pila.fr/wordpress/?p=361) I found how to configure the TTY with termios to set the correct baudrate, parity etc so I have a working bidirectional communication between the minitel and my program.

Now for the problem: **the minitel is using some weird non-standard escape sequences** for some of its keys. For reference:

```
Sommaire   27  79  80
Annulation 27  79  81
Retour     27  79  82
Répétition 27  79  83
Guide      27  79  109
Correction 27  79  108
Suite      27  79  110
Envoi      27  79  77
```

When I'm using any of these keys the escape sequences are not recognized, so I get a bunch of weird characters echoed back. **Is there a way to configure the TTY in order to manage those specific escape sequences?**

So far, **the only approach I found is to switch to raw mode** - in which case I can manage custom escape sequences, but I also have to manage everything else (echo, new lines etc).

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do, but those escapes look not very different from e.g. what the arrow or function keys generate in a terminal emulator. For instance, in bash you can `bind '"\eOP": "Sommaire!"'` to have `Sommaire!` entered when you press that key. (you can also bind it to some function, shell command, etc)

Comment: `Suite` is even present in the terminfo entry for `minitel` from my system, as "Next Page": `infocmp minitel | grep On` => `knp=\EOn`.

Comment: ok that's interesting, I didn't know about bind in bash.So maybe I'm just making my life miserable by accessing the tty directly, and I'd rather define a new getty that starts bash then my application. thanks for your input!